# Scratchy bokeh - do I have a problem with my lens?

Tags: lens, bokeh

I'm using a Sony G 70-300/4.5-5.6 SSM lens, paired with a Sony A-E mount converter and an A7Rii.

[image]
https://ibb.co/kifF1k

The above shot is a 100% crop of a photo taken at f5.6 300m.  I always get these scratchy slanting lines, all going in the same direction, approx 30 degrees from the horizontal.  I get some pretty decent shots but I have definitely noticed that even my best pictures are not as sharp as a guy I know who uses pro Canon kit.

Do I have a problem with my lens?  Should I ditch the mount converter and get an e-mount lens or is this scratchy appearance normal with this lens?

(I bought the lens 2nd hand)

Comment: Wow that is unusual!!!, looking forwards to answers on this... OIS based weirdness maybe?!

Comment: Could be any number of effects.  You need to post the entire image and the EXIF data to improve the odds someone has an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In trying to take a suitable image to use as a full example, I removed the UV filter I have on the end to act as protector - problem apparently solved.

Lesson learnt: cheap glass is cheap for a reason.

Comment: FYI, it's ok to accept your own answer. There might even be a badge to encourage it.

Comment: Will do, but I have to wait until tomorrow.